# How do I simulate network time?

Tags: wi-fi

I want to ask, how do I simulate other timezone (Like +13:00) on network? Like all apps that get time from network will get custom time.

Answer (score 0):

Often apps only take your system time to do certain task. So if you want to simulate another timezone, just change it in your phones settings.

If this doesn't work for you, you still can get the Android Emulator. It is normally used by developers to test their app, but you can test everything there